# Using split function for multiple data

Tags: python, python-3.x

so for my problem, I have to create a program that takes a users input, and then prints it like a list. For example, if the user inputs "I like doing this activity, the program should return it as.

```
I
like
doing
this
activity.
```

But these should work with any scenario that the user inputs.

I tried using the input function and split to try and define the variables

```
my_list_of_data = input("Enter your sentence:").split()
print("(%s),/n(%s),/n(%s),/n(%s),/n(%s)"%(my_list_of_data))
```

I am getting an error in line 2, saying there is not enough arguments to create a string.

Comment: What's the contents of `my_list_of_data` when you get this error?

Comment: `print("\n".join(my_list_of_data))`?

Comment: You're passing **a single list** to the first `%s`; `%` formatting special-cases tuples, so try `print("(%s),/n(%s),/n(%s),/n(%s),/n(%s)"%tuple(my_list_of_data))`. But now you have the problem of extra parentheses and `/n` not being a newline...

Comment: Newline is `\n`.

Comment: I was just trying the example above, with I like doing this activity when getting this error, @munk

Comment: Regex is way overkill for a problem like this. Use something like the answer below.

Answer (score 2):

Print the list like this:

```py
print('\n'.join(my_list_of_data))
```